# Batch issue with directory names

Tags: windows, batch-file

I noticed that my batch script doesn't work properly if there are any spaces in folder names:

C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\abc\def\example.bat → all tasks are done correctly

C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\def\example.bat → wrong behaviour

**What changes must occur?**

{ *example.bat* }

```
@echo off

for %%F in ("%~dp0..\*.wgm") do (
set "file=%%~nxF"
move "%%F" "%cd%" >nul
goto :next
)
:next
if not exist %cd%\output md output
if not exist %cd%\temp md temp

echo File "%file%" was moved from "%~dp0..\" to "%cd%" && move "*.wgm" "%cd%\"

for /d %%i in ("%cd%\") do ( cd "%%i" ) && for %%i in (*.wgm) do tool.exe *.wgm "%%~ni".dat "643054977005802"

move "%cd%\*.wgm" temp\
move "%cd%\*.dat" output\

if exist %~dp0..\*.wgm call example.bat
if not exist %~dp0..\*.wgm goto :last

:last
for /r %%x in (*.dat) do ren "%%x" *.wgm
move "%cd%\temp\*.wgm" %~dp0..\ && rmdir /s /q "%cd%\temp"

exit
```

Comment: In brief, anything that might contain a space needs to be enclosed in double-quotes. So like you have `move "%cd%\*.wgm" temp\ ` at one point, a few lines earlier you'd need `if not exist "%cd%\output" md output`. (Although from a quick glance you shouldn't actually need to use `%cd%` most of the time because, by definition, you're already _in_ the current directory).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I added some quotes, but now there is one last problem. The batch doesn't call the commands under :last anymore. Any idea why?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no. If you want someone to help more, you'd need to **(a)** edit the question to show the current state of the code; **(b)** describe specific "test-conditions" (i.e. what `.wgm` and `.dat` files you have where); and **(c)** show exactly what output you get (including any error messages, if any).

Comment: Thanks for your help! All issues solved now.

Answer (score 0):

New version of the Batch script:

```
@echo off
set "target=%cd%\output_decrypted"
for %%F in ("%~dp0..\*.wgm") do (
set "file=%%~nxF"
move "%%F" "%cd%" >nul
goto :next )
:next
if not exist "%target%\" md "%target%"
if not exist "temp" md temp
echo File "%file%" was moved from "%~dp0..\" to "%cd%" && move "*.wgm" "%cd%\"
for /d %%i in ("%cd%\") do ( cd "%%i" ) && for %%i in (*.wgm) do tool.exe *.wgm "%%~ni".dat "643054977005802"
move "%cd%\*.wgm" "temp\"
move "%cd%\*.dat" "output\"
if exist "%~dp0..\*.wgm" call example.bat 2>nul
if not exist "%~dp0..\*.wgm" goto :last
:last
for /r %%x in (*.dat) do ren "%%x" *.wgm && move "%cd%\temp\*.wgm" "%~dp0..\" && rmdir /s /q "%cd%\temp"
exit
```